# How to get consistent date format in the "Files" GUI?

Tags: gui, filemanager, timestamp

On Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, when I use the "File" GUI to browse the filesystem, the timestamps are displayed very inconsistently:

[image]

Seeing at least four different formats is more than a little confusing when visually scanning through the list.

Is there some way to get a consistent format?

("`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`" would be ideal, but anything that's uniform would be an improvement).

Comment: if you use the collum "modification date" instead of "last modification" it's more consistent and also purposefully alligned so that it's easy to read : does that work for you : https://imgur.com/a/USpbSvQ ?

Comment: @tatsu, In "preferences", I see "Modified" and "Modified - Time", both of which are irregular.

Comment: well I find the second one to at  least be aligned.